# maven : mvn clean package throwing error "Input is not in the XZ format. "

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

While doing 
    ***mvn clean package***

i am getting following error :

```
    [ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition C:\Users\xyz\git\sql-converter sql.target.target: 

Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location download.eclipse.org/releases/neon: 

Unable to read repository at http://download
    .eclipse.org/releases/neon. 

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201606221000. 

Input is not in the XZ format -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1]
```

can anyone please throw light on the same.
I am unable to find anything related to error : 
"*Input is not in the XZ format.*"

For more details, when I visited the site [releases/neon/201703231000/artifacts.xml.xz](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000/artifacts.xml.xz), I got the error message below:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000/artifacts.xml.xz
Line Number 1, Column 1:7zXZ
```

- Do you think it is normal? For the other files, for instance [releases/neon/201703231000/content.xml.xz](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000/content.xml.xz), it is possible to download. They are both in the XZ format.
- Does the message mean something wrong happened while generating the file?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem accessing  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201606221000 which is causing input in not in xz format error.
I just changed the update site to any one of the below :

```
    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201606221000/
    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201609281000/
    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201610111000/
    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000/
    http://download.eclipse.org/e4/snapshots/org.eclipse.e4.tools/latest/
```

and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In our problem, we are using maven with tycho plug-in for building an eclipse rcp application.
The tycho version we used is **0.24.0**.

```
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:jar:0.24.0:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-facade:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-core:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1:compile
[DEBUG]             org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]                commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state:jar:1.0.100.v20150402-1551:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-metadata-model:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]             de.pdark:decentxml:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-embedder-api:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-embedder:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.101.v20150820-1432:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-launching:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-api:jar:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-standalone-p2-director:zip:0.24.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.4:compile
```

While running `maven clean install -X` I have the stack below:

```
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201703231000.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.loadRepository(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$LoadedIULocation.<init>(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver$ResolverRun.addLocation(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContentWithExceptions(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolver.resolveContent(TargetDefinitionResolver.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.resolveFromArguments(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetDefinitionResolverService.getTargetDefinitionContent(TargetDefinitionResolverService.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.resolveTargetDefinitions(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format
        at org.tukaani.xz.common.DecoderUtil.decodeStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:80)
```

Which means we have some problem with the **org.tukaani.xz**. 
I compared then with another build using **tycho version 1.0.0**, I found that with this version, tycho depends on ***org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile*** and this one does not depend anymore on ***org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.4:compile***. So, I updated the tycho version to **1.0.0** and the build was working.

> So one solution could be: if your maven build uses tycho, check the
>   tycho version in pom.xml, if it is 0.24.0 or below 1.0.0, you should
>   consider to upgrade it to 1.0.0